# Regex match on whole .csv file

Tags: regex, perl, csv

Good Morning!

I'm struggling with a problem, I never thought it would be one. I have a **.csv** file with seperator `;` which I like to check with respect of its syntax. It looks like this:

```
wellenname;tag
Welle A;01/02/2016
Welle B3;14/11/2016
server;welle
server5name032;Welle B3 Rand
server3name01;Welle A
server2name;Welle B3
```

So I have a beautiful formatted **.csv** file which I can process with a regex. Therefore I constructed four cases for the regex:

1. wellenname;tag\n
2. (Welle [A-Z]+[0-9]*;\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\n)+
3. server;welle\n
4. (\S*;Welle [a-z,A-Z,0-9]+( Rand)*(\n)*)+

This worked quiet beautiful in a Tool named **The Regex Coach** which basically tries to match a regexp and a string and outputs where it struggles.

Then I put it together in Perl. Reading the file and checking the syntax:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $filename = 'theFile.csv';

my $content;

open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
$content = join('',<$fh>);

if ($content =~ /wellenname;tag\n(Welle [A-Z]+[0-9]*;\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n)+server;welle\n(\S*;Welle [a-z,A-Z,0-9]+( Rand)*(\n)*)+/) { 
  print "Syntax seems to be valid!";

}else{
  print "You have syntax errors!";
}
```

I went through the file line by line, but even if I insert only one entry per section it fails. (or better: It jumps to the **else** and prints the string)

Did I forgot sth. or is there a mayor mistake in my thinking?
I would be very pleased if somebody could give me a hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this actually works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $content = join('',<DATA>);

if ($content =~ /wellenname;tag\n(Welle [A-Z]+[0-9]*;\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\n)+server;welle\n(\S*;Welle [a-z,A-Z,0-9]+( Rand)*(\n)*)+/) {
  print "Syntax seems to be valid!";
} else {
  print "You have syntax errors!";
}

__DATA__
wellenname;tag
Welle A;01/02/2016
Welle B3;14/11/2016
server;welle
server5name032;Welle B3 Rand
server3name01;Welle A
server2name;Welle B3
```

There is a chance you have a problem with your file. Maybe you have to search for **\r\n** instead of **\n** when it's a windows-generated file.

But your regex still is not perfect.

First of all, you miss `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end of the regex respectively. Now it can match CSV with the extra symbols before and after your actual CSV. Second, you don't need commas inside `[]`, so `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]` should be `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (or it would match `,` as well as other symbols you specified). Also, you should consider using `/x` switch (to make your regex more readable) and use `m{...}` instead of `/.../` to not escape `/` inside of the regex.

So, my final version is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = join('',<DATA>);

if (
    $content =~ m{
        ^
        wellenname;tag\n
        (Welle[ ][A-Z]+[0-9]*;\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\n)+
        server;welle\n
        (\S*;Welle[ ][a-z,A-Z,0-9]+([ ]Rand)*(\n)*)+
        $
    }x
) {
  print 'Syntax seems to be valid!';
}
else {
  print 'You have syntax errors!';
}

__DATA__
wellenname;tag
Welle A;01/02/2016
Welle B3;14/11/2016
server;welle
server5name032;Welle B3 Rand
server3name01;Welle A
server2name;Welle B3
```

Mind that I use `[ ]` to match space while using `/x`. I also use `'...'` instead of `"..."`, because we don't need interpolation enabled in that strings.

Comment: Well you solved indirectly the problem! With the hint to check my file more carefully, I noticed that the **.csv** ist a windows-styled file so I had to search for \r\n rather than just only \n!
When I tried your (working!) example I check the file for its coding and ... yeah, maybe a novice fault, but actually the solution ;)

And your tips a very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again, I tried the m{} and /x and they work just fine. Leaving out the `,` in the `[ ]` makes it actually more readable too.

Comment: `,` in `[]` means it will match `,` too that is *not* what you want

Comment: Yes, I just thoght so. Actually I put the `,` in betweend the values because I just typed what I constucted on paper building a regular expression without thinking of the perl-Syntax of regexes. Thanks for your advise!